# using xsl:fallback correctly

Tags: xslt, saxon

I'm trying to incorporate xsl:fallback into my stylesheets. I am using Saxon9.5.1.23-HE.

I tried this code in a named template that I'm calling:

```
<xsl:newstuff>
    <xsl:text>blabla</xsl:text>
    <xsl:fallback>
       <xsl:message>
          Fallback worked!
       </xsl:message>
    </xsl:fallback>
</xsl:newstuff>
```

But instead of "Fallback worked", I get the message that the element newstuff is unkown.

Am I doing something wrong or does it have to do with the version of Saxon I am using?

I havent found anything on the Saxon website yet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ian Roberts gives the correct diagnosis, I think.  To test fallback mode, put version="4.0" (or something similar, some version number greater than what the processor supports) on the xsl:stylesheet element, or xsl:version="4.0" on the xsl:newstuff element (or an ancestor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<xsl:fallback>` is only processed in [forwards-compatible mode](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#dt-forwards-compatible-behavior) when the `version="..."` on the `xsl:stylesheet` element is greater than the maximum version supported by the processor in question (i.e. "I only understand XSLT 2.0 but this stylesheet is 4.0, so I'll give you the benefit of the doubt").  If the processor understands the version of XSLT that you claim for your stylesheet then it is correct to reject elements it does not recognise rather than using the fallback ("I understand XSLT 2.0, this stylesheet is 2.0, therefore I *know* for certain that this element is wrong").

Comment: aahh... thanks a lot! It worked now! I thought it was supposed to be an element that you could always use to catch an error. Thanx again!